# How to add columns to multi-index dataframes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-index dataframe that looks like this:

```
       ACA FP Equity            UCG IM Equity            
          LAST PRICE     VOLUME    LAST PRICE      VOLUME
date                                                         
2010-01-04        12.825  5879617.0       15.0292  10844639.0
2010-01-05        13.020  6928587.0       14.8092  16456228.0
2010-01-06        13.250  5290631.0       14.6834  10446450.0
2010-01-07        13.255  5328586.0       15.0292  31900341.0
2010-01-08        13.470  7160295.0       15.1707  40750768.0
```

If I want to add a third column in the dataframe for each equity, what is the syntax? For instance:

```
df['ACA FP Equity']['PriceVolume'] = df['ACA FP Equity']['LAST PRICE']*3
```

but I want to do it for each equity, without manually adding each one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need all of the `LAST PRICE` columns multiplied by `3` select them using [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) and rename the column name:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'LAST PRICE']].rename(columns={'LAST PRICE':'PriceVolume'}) * 3
print (df1)
           ACA FP Equity UCG IM Equity
             PriceVolume   PriceVolume
2010-01-04        38.475       45.0876
2010-01-05        39.060       44.4276
2010-01-06        39.750       44.0502
2010-01-07        39.765       45.0876
2010-01-08        40.410       45.5121
```

then you need to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the output:

```
print (pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1))
           ACA FP Equity            UCG IM Equity             ACA FP Equity  \
              LAST PRICE     VOLUME    LAST PRICE      VOLUME   PriceVolume   
2010-01-04        12.825  5879617.0       15.0292  10844639.0        38.475   
2010-01-05        13.020  6928587.0       14.8092  16456228.0        39.060   
2010-01-06        13.250  5290631.0       14.6834  10446450.0        39.750   
2010-01-07        13.255  5328586.0       15.0292  31900341.0        39.765   
2010-01-08        13.470  7160295.0       15.1707  40750768.0        40.410   

           UCG IM Equity  
             PriceVolume  
2010-01-04       45.0876  
2010-01-05       44.4276  
2010-01-06       44.0502  
2010-01-07       45.0876  
2010-01-08       45.5121
```

Another solution without `concat` is to create tuples from columns of `selected_df` and then assign output:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
selected_df = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'LAST PRICE']]

new_cols = [(x, 'PriceVolume') for x in selected_df.columns.levels[0]]
print (new_cols)
[('ACA FP Equity', 'PriceVolume'), ('UCG IM Equity', 'PriceVolume')]

df[new_cols] = selected_df * 3
print(df)
           ACA FP Equity            UCG IM Equity             ACA FP Equity  \
              LAST PRICE     VOLUME    LAST PRICE      VOLUME   PriceVolume   
2010-01-04        12.825  5879617.0       15.0292  10844639.0        38.475   
2010-01-05        13.020  6928587.0       14.8092  16456228.0        39.060   
2010-01-06        13.250  5290631.0       14.6834  10446450.0        39.750   
2010-01-07        13.255  5328586.0       15.0292  31900341.0        39.765   
2010-01-08        13.470  7160295.0       15.1707  40750768.0        40.410   

           UCG IM Equity  
             PriceVolume  
2010-01-04       45.0876  
2010-01-05       44.4276  
2010-01-06       44.0502  
2010-01-07       45.0876  
2010-01-08       45.5121
```

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant way I can think of is:

```
df['ACA FP Equity']['PriceVolume'] = pd.Series(df['ACA FP Equity']['LAST PRICE'].apply(lambda x: x*3))
```

The [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) statement lets you execute a given function, in this case a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) that multiplies each input by three, for each value of a specified column in the dataframe.  Running the apply statement will return a pandas [Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html#pandas.Series) which can then be added as a column in the dataframe.

Here is a simple example showing how it would work with a simple dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
print(df)

# Output:
# /  a  b
# 0  1  4
# 1  2  5
# 2  3  6


# Add column 'c'
df['c'] = pd.Series(df['b'].apply(lambda x: x*3))
print(df)

# Output:
# /  a  b  c
# 0  1  4  12
# 1  2  5  15
# 2  3  6  18
```